# Moving files with incremented files name padded by zeros to directories in Perl

Tags: perl, directory, printf, filenames, move

I have files `0001_test.txt` to `0100_test.txt`. I make directories Dir1 and Dir2. I want to move files `0001_test.txt` to `0010_test.txt` to directory Dir1.

my current  script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my @files = <*.txt>;
my $files;
my $count;

for $files (@files) {
  ++$count;
  mkdir -p "Dir1";
  mkdir -p "Dir2";
   if ($count >= 1 && $count <= 10) {
   my $basename = printf "%04d" $count; 
   mv "($basename)_test.txt" "Dir1";
   }
}
```

This obviously fails, so how would one correct this?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with testing that. Did you have a programming question?

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, I thought that it was obvious to people that read perl that this script fails...

Comment: @ChemistnotaProgrammer: Sure, but what isn't obvious is why you haven't tried particularly hard to fix it before asking us to do it for you. Googling `Perl mkdir` would get you a long way towards a solution

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very odd. `Dir2` doesn't appear to have any bearing on the problem, and I don't see how you expect `mkdir -p "Dir1"` to do anything useful in a Perl program. However, this should solve your problem

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy 'move';
use File::Path 'make_path';

my @dirs = ( 'Dir1', 'Dir2' );

make_path $_ for @dirs;

my @files = glob '*.txt';

my $n;
for my $file ( sort @files ) {
  next unless $file =~ /\A\d{4}_test\.txt\z/;

  my $new_file = sprintf '%s/%04d_test.txt', $dirs[0], ++$n;
  move $file, $new_file;
  last if $n == 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful!

Answer (score -1):

Easy solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy 'move';

my @files = <*.txt>;
my $count;

mkdir "Dir1";
mkdir "Dir2";

my @dir = <Dir*>;

for my $files (@files) {
  ++$count;
   if ($count >= 1 && $count <= 9) {
   my $move_files = sprintf '%s/%04d_test.text', $dir[0], $count;
   move ($files, $move_files);
   }
}
```